# Eclipse Keyboard Shortcut for “resize editors left or right" when open editors side by side?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, development-environment

When i open my `Eclipse` editors side by side
As that
[image]
How i can by `Eclipse Keyboard Shortcut` not by mouse
To resize an editor to make it more lagrger or more smaller

Comment: I'd like to know this too. Furthermore, is there a hotkey to switch between the two quickly?